# Open in New Tab using ctrl+click stays focus on the current page but contextmenu/rightclick changes focus to the new tab

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I  have the following JS code on a VueJS page

```
if (isCtrlClick){
    const itemDetailsData = this.$router.resolve({name:'ItemDetails', params: { id: id, name: itemName, source: this.source }});
    var keepFocus = window.open(itemDetailsData.href, "_blank");
    keepFocus.blur();
    window.focus();
}
else {
    const itemDetailsData = this.$router.resolve({name:'ItemDetails', params: { sid: itemx.id, upc: itemx.itemName, source: this.source }});
    var keepFocus = window.open(itemDetailsData.href, "_blank");
    var currentWindow = window;
    keepFocus.blur();
    currentWindow.focus();
}
```

If I do control+click the new tab opens in the background which is the expected behavior, but if do rightclick and then select the open in new tab option, it does open the new tab as expected but it also changes the focus to the new tab instead of staying on the current one.

As you can see in my code snippet, they are both the same but they behave different. Any ideas what can i do?

Comment: this behavior is browser dependent.  if you're relying on this working the same way for all browsers -- dont.

Comment: well, so far is the same behavior on chrome, firefox or edge. But yes, i agree with you about it being browser specific. I also check for shift+click and open in new window, they work on chrome and edge, but firefox opens a newtab